# Elasticsearch 2.x, query for tag, and sort results by tag weigth

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

i am using elasticsearch 2.3

i have an index of books. each book has tag, and each tag has weight.
i want to get all books that have the requested tag, sorted by tag weight.

for example:

```
PUT book/book/0
{
    "name": "book 0",
    "tags": [
        {"t": "comedy", "w": 30},
        {"t": "drama","w": 20},
    ]
}

PUT book/book/1
{
    "name": "book 1",
    "tags": [
        {"t": "comedy", "w": 10},
        {"t": "drama","w": 5},
        {"t": "other","w": 50},
    ]
}

PUT book/book/2
    {
        "name": "book 2",
        "tags": [
            {"t": "comedy", "w": 5},
            {"t": "drama","w": 30},
        ]
    }

PUT book/book/3
    {
        "name": "book 3",
        "tags": [
            {"t": "comedy", "w": 5},
            {"t": "other","w": 30},
        ]
    }
```

i want to search for all books that has tags comedy and drama.
the result order is:

1. book 0 (20+30)
2. book 2 (30+5)
3. book 1 (10+5)

UPDATE:
i want to return only books that match both tags (and sort only by requested tags). so if i search for 'drama' and 'comedy', only books that has both tags will return (in this case book 0, book 1, book2), sorted by requested tag weights.

how can i get this? any example for query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ibrahim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955676/235203) is correct if you always want to sum up all weights, even for tags that don't match your query.

If you only want to take the weights of tags into account that you're searching for, you'll have to index `tags` as a `nested` object. This is because otherwise all `t`s and `w`s are flattened into lists, losing the associations in the process (described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_how_arrays_of_objects_are_flattened)).

Then you can use a `function_score` query wrapped in a `nested` query to sum up only the weights of the matching tags. You will have to enable [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html).

Here is an example:

```
GET /book/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "tags",
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "tags.t": [
                      "comedy",
                      "drama"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "functions": [
            {
              "script_score": {
                "script": "return doc['tags.w'].value"
              }
            }
          ],
          "boost_mode": "replace"
        }
      },
      "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

---

**=== EDIT following @Eyal Ch's comment ===**

If only books matching BOTH tags (comedy and drama in the example) are to be returned, it gets a bit more complicated, as each search term needs its own `nested` query.

Here's an example:

```
GET /book/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must":
      [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "function_score": {
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "tags.t": {
                      "value": "comedy"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "functions": [
                  {
                    "script_score": {
                      "script": "return doc['tags.w'].value"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "boost_mode": "replace"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "tags",
            "query": {
              "function_score": {
                "query": {
                  "term": {
                    "tags.t": {
                      "value": "drama"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "functions": [
                  {
                    "script_score": {
                      "script": "return doc['tags.w'].value"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "boost_mode": "replace"
              }
            }
          }
        }
     ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Christoph Wurm. the only issue i have now is that this will return all books that  comedy or drama in tags. but i need all books that comedy AND drama in tags. can you help?

Comment: @EyalCh Yeah, I put it into the answer.

Comment: thanks that works!. just to understand: in your updated answer, i do not see "score_mode": "sum". how it summerize the score? is it by default? if i want to score it in a different score (like avg?). thanks.

Comment: The wrapping query is a `bool`. It operates on the assumption that matching more clauses is better, so it will sum up the scores. There's no way to change that behavior.

I guess if you wanted the average you could divide by the total number of clauses in each `script`, but that's starting to look a bit hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
POST book/book/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
           "tags.t": "comedy drama"
        }
    },
    "sort": [
       {
          "tags.w": {
             "order": "desc",
             "mode": "sum"
          }
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this will sort by 'w' of all tags. i want to sort it only by the order of the requested tags (w of comedy + w of drama)